# How to call mouse over function on dyanamic divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic divs as rows:

```
<table border=1><tr><td>
<div id='div1'>fgg</div>
<div id='div2'>dfgdfg</div>
<div id='div3'>vcbcvb</div>
<div id='div4'>sdfsdf</div>
</td></tr></table>
```

How can I call jQuery function on mouseover of each div?
These divs are dynamic, can vary the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("td div").live("mouseover", function() {
 //mouseover code here
});
```

I suggest using a class for your divs, and using a selector: `$(".rows")` or similar. However, the above will work for the markup you've given.

**If you must use id**, this will allow you to add it by id. Keep in mind that as you add new items, you will have to run this code for the id (defeating the dynamic part of your original question).

```
$("#mydivid").mouseover(function() {
  //mouseover code here
});
```

which you could utilize in a list like so:

```
var divs = ["mydiv1", "mydiv2", "mydiv3"];
$(divs).each(function() {
  $("#" + this).mouseover(function() {
    //mouseover code here
  });
});
```

This is really a bad approach, I **strongly** suggest using a class instead.

Comment: this working fine, but this will affect the entire divs in the tds. Can i have 5 divs with id mydiv andi want to call only these divs, is it possible. i try its not working.$("td div mydiv").live  . any solution

Comment: I would suggest using a class for the divs you want to apply it to, and then use a $(".rows") selector or similar. If you must do it by id, and not class, you will want to use the form that I am adding to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use event delegation, either [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind events to elements that are created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

one another easy way is to give the same class name to all the divs.
you can hook the click event by class name instead of id.In the code you can also refer the current div block by using "this" keyword

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some reason you specifically cannot use a repeating class name for each div, the `live()` method is the way to go. Using a class would be much more efficient, however.